# All binary sequences in R

Tags: r, binary

I'm trying to write a recursive function that takes as input an integer n and returns a matrix that contains all binary sequences of length n.
I wrote this code but it is not giving an output

```
binseq <- function(n){
binsequ <- matrix(nrow = length(n), ncol = n)
r <- 0 # current row of binseq
for (i in 0:n) {
for (j in 0:n) {
for (k in 0:n) {
r <- r + 1
return (binsequ[r,] <- c(i, j, k))
}
}
}
}
```

I tried to run it using n=3

```
binseq(3)
```

But with no success.
However, when I do not use the function command and give specific numbers, it works. For example,

```
binseq <- matrix(nrow = 8, ncol = 3)
r <- 0 # current row of binseq
for (i in 0:1) {
for (j in 0:1) {
for (k in 0:1) {
r <- r + 1
binseq[r,] <- c(i, j, k)
}
}
}
binseq
```

the output is:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    1
[3,]    0    1    0
[4,]    0    1    1
[5,]    1    0    0
[6,]    1    0    1
[7,]    1    1    0
[8,]    1    1    1
```

Comment: would `expand.grid(replicate(3, c(0,1), simplify=FALSE))` do the job for you ?

Comment: Problem is that using `<-` inside `return` doesn't actually return the LHS of the assignment. Re-position the `return` call to only surround the `binseq`-name outside the loops, (or just don't use return since it wouldn't be needed.)

Answer (score 0):

I created a function, was thinking about doing recursive but it turned out to be using loop. Hope to see how others did this as this sounds like a quite basic question. Landed here. If helps, here is my function.

```
##k: number of digits, k>1, eg k=3 for 101 etc

binary_gen <- function(k) {

base <- c(0L,1L)

##initialize
bi.set <- integer(2^(k))
bi.set[1:2] <- base

##create set through loop
for (i in 2:k) {

  bi.set[(2^(i-1)+1):2^i] <- 10^(i-1)+bi.set[1:2^(i-1)] 
  bi.set
  
}

return(bi.set)

}
```

Here is output for k=4.

```
> binary_gen(4L)
```

[1]    0    1   10   11  100  101  110  111 1000 1001 1010 1011 1100 1101 1110 1111

You can manipulate the output vector into a matrix of desired format (# of rows=k, # of columns=2^k). Based on k, the location for binary numbers of k digits are 2^(k-1)+1 to 2^k.